# Using bash wildcards with prefix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, wildcard

I am trying to write a bash script that takes a variable number of file names as arguments.
The script is processing those files and creating a temporary file for each of those files.

To access the arguments in a loop I am using

```
for filename in $*
do
   ...
   generate t_$(filename)
done
```

After the loop is done, I want to do something like `cat t_$*` .
But it's not working. So, if the arguments are `a b c`, it is catting `t_a, b and c`.
I want to cat the files `t_a, t_b and t_c`.

Is there anyway to do this without having to save the list of names in another variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Parameter expansion:

```
cat "${@/#/t_}"
```

`/` means substitute, `#` means at the beginning.